# How do I check which version of NumPy I'm using?

Tags: python, numpy, version

How can I check which version of NumPy I'm using?

Comment: probable you just need to install specific version of [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520234/how-do-i-check-which-version-of-numpy-im-using/53898417#53898417)

Answer (score 477, accepted):

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
```

Comment: This is not the public API, numpy.__version__ is.

Comment: Actually `import numpy ; numpy.version.version` . The lack of `import numpy` through me, an obvious newbie.

Comment: Since the use of `__version__` in recommended in PEP8 and most packages support `__version__` vs the non standard `version.version` I think that this answer should be treated more as a curiosity than an accepted method. Use `numpy.__version__` or `<package>.__version__` as [Dominic Rodger's answer recommends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1520264/298607) Parse the version (and create your own version strings) as recommended in PEP 386 / PEP 440.

Comment: Actually, in NumPy 1.20, `numpy.version.version` is typed, and `numpy.__version__` is not (could be an oversight).

Answer (score 293):

```
import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)
```

Comment: This is the API we numpy developers will support. numpy.version.version is an implementation detail that should not be relied upon.

Comment: well, this works for most well-written python packages.

Comment: This is the PEP8 Way(tm) +1

Comment: for Python 3 and the standard numpy import name use `print(np.__version__)`

Answer (score 84):

From the command line, you can simply issue:

```
python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version.version)"
```

Or:

```
python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
```

Comment: This is actually very nice as it allows you to check the version of numpy even if you have two different versions running on two different versions of python. 
py -2  -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version.version)"
py -3  -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version.version)"

Answer (score 37):

Run:

```
pip list
```

Should generate a list of packages. Scroll through to numpy.

```
...
nbpresent (3.0.2)
networkx (1.11)
nltk (3.2.2)
nose (1.3.7)
notebook (5.0.0)
numba (0.32.0+0.g139e4c6.dirty)
numexpr (2.6.2)
numpy (1.11.3) <--
numpydoc (0.6.0)
odo (0.5.0)
openpyxl (2.4.1)
pandas (0.20.1)
pandocfilters (1.4.1)
....
```

Comment: Or `pip freeze` if in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 19):

You can also check if your version is using MKL with:

```
import numpy
numpy.show_config()
```

Answer (score 13):

You can try this:

> pip show numpy

Answer (score 11):

We can use `pip freeze` to get any Python package version without opening the Python shell.

```
pip freeze | grep 'numpy'
```

Comment: That only works if you installed numpy via pip, not via brew or apt-get, for example.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using ***NumPy from the Anaconda distribution***, then you can just do:

```
$ conda list | grep numpy
numpy     1.11.3     py35_0
```

This gives the `Python` version as well.

---

#### If you want something fancy, then use `numexpr`

It gives lot of information as you can see below:

```
In [692]: import numexpr

In [693]: numexpr.print_versions()
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Numexpr version:   2.6.2
NumPy version:     1.13.3
Python version:    3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)|
                   (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49)
[GCC 7.2.0]
Platform:          linux-x86_64
AMD/Intel CPU?     True
VML available?     False
Number of threads used by default: 8 (out of 48 detected cores)
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

Comment: Or `conda list numpy`

Answer (score 7):

Simply

```
pip show numpy
```

and for pip3

```
pip3 show numpy
```

Works on both windows and linux. Should work on mac too if you are using pip.

Answer (score 5):

You can get numpy version using Terminal or a Python code.

In a Terminal (bash) using Ubuntu:

```
pip list | grep numpy
```

In python 3.6.7, this code shows the numpy version:

```
import numpy
print (numpy.version.version)
```

If you insert this code in the file shownumpy.py, you can compile it:

```
python shownumpy.py
```

or

```
python3 shownumpy.py
```

I've got this output:

```
1.16.1
```

Comment: Just a slight caution that it's possible that you may have python and python 3 both installed with numpy. Then when doing the `pip list | grep numpy` method it will show one of the two (typically the python 3's numpy version). When you run the `shownumpy.py` program on both python and python 3, they will show you exactly what version is on each respective python environment.

Answer (score 4):

Just a slight solution change for checking the version of numpy with Python,

```
import numpy as np 
print("Numpy Version:",np.__version__)
```

Or,

```
import numpy as np
print("Numpy Version:",np.version.version)
```

My projects in PyCharm are currently running version

```
1.17.4
```

Answer (score 3):

For Python 3.X print syntax:

```
python -c "import numpy; print (numpy.version.version)"
```

Or

```
python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of the answer of @meduz . For python 3, it is `print(numpy.__version__)`, not `print numpy.__version__`

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy
print numpy.__version__
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Python shell:

```
>>> help()
help> numpy
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows**

```
pip list | FINDSTR numpy
```

**For Linux**

```
pip list | grep numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure Python line that can be executed from the terminal (both 2.X and 3.X versions):

```
python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version.version)"
```

If you are already inside Python, then:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.version.version)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good to know the version of `numpy` you run, but strictly speaking if you just need to have specific version on your system you can write like this:

`pip install numpy==1.14.3`  and this will install the version you need and uninstall other versions of `numpy`.