# Managing requirements in IPython Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am a Python programmer, new to IPython Notebook. I have started a notebook that uses `numpy`.

If I was publishing the same code as a standalone Python script, I'd include a `requirements.txt` file with `numpy` and its version, so that other users can install the same version into a virtualenv when they run the script.

What is the equivalent of this for iPython Notebook? I can't find anything about managing requirements in [the documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/), only about the dependencies required to install IPython itself.

My requirements are that I'd like to make sure that the notebook is using a particular version of `numpy`, and I want to make sure that I can publish the notebook with the same version specified.

Answer (score 7):

If you have *Jupyter* in your `requirements.txt` and you activate that environment (I recommend [*Virtualenv*](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)), install, and run *Jupyter*, you'll have all the specific versions you want. So:

1. `python3 -m venv venv`
2. `source venv/bin/activate` (*Windows*: `venv\Scripts\activate`)
3. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. `jupyter lab` (or `jupyter notebook`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by importing `numpy` and then checking `numpy.__version__`. Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520234/how-to-check-which-version-of-numpy-im-using).

Comment: I think OP's question is more general. This approach will only work for a small subset of packages and is quite cumbersome for multiple dependencies.

Comment: I'm basing my answer on @dawg 's comment in the post to which I link: "The use of `__version__ `is recommended in PEP8... Most packages support `__version__`...  Parse the version (and create your own version strings) as recommended in PEP 386 / PEP 440."