# Numpy.core.multiarray doesn't work anymore after opencv installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, tensorflow

I am using python 2.7 on anaconda notebook on mac.
Numpy was working perfectly along with `tensorflow` until I tried to install OpenCV using (pip install OpenCV). It now produces an error as shown

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x7
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I have tried all the ways to install numpy, but I keep getting this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I even tried to reinstall it and install it again, but still, the same message shows up.

Comment: From the exception it clearly indicates that numpy versions are not matching. You can check numpy versions as follows. I will also think how to further narrow down and fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520234/how-to-check-which-version-of-numpy-im-using

Comment: I guess following page will help you to fix it, please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517937/how-can-i-upgrade-numpy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859531/runtimeerror-module-compiled-against-api-version-a-but-this-version-of-numpy-is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to upgrade numpy

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Then check your path:

```
import numpy
print numpy.__path__
```

Maybe you need to move some files, look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859531/runtimeerror-module-compiled-against-api-version-a-but-this-version-of-numpy-is) question.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  pip install numpy --upgrade solved the problem :D